# Getting value from a function

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord

My code works but not how I would like it to. 
The output on discord is `Your name is undefined`. 
And I would like it to be `Your name is Boanak`. I need it to be the value that it gets from the table.

I'm orking on a bot on discord where the user has to be registered to use some commands in it. Thanks in advance!

```
getPlayerid = function(client, message, callback){
var member = message.member.user;
var db = new sqlite3.Database('Matches');
db.serialize(function() {
    db.all(`SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Nameid =`+member.id, function(err, allRows){
        if(err != null){
            //console.log(err);
            callback(0);
        }
        callback(allRows);
        db.close();
    });
});
}


z = getPlayerid(client, message, function(data){
})
message.channel.send(`Your Name is ${z}`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is asynchrone so your variable cannot be used outside your function.

I think you have to do somethig like this :

```
var getPlayerid = function(client, message, callback) {
    var member = message.member.user;
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('Matches');
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.all(`SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Nameid =`+member.id, function(err, allRows){
            if(err) {
                //console.log(err);
                callback(err, null);
            }
            else {
                callback(null, allRows);
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
};


getPlayerid(client, message, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else if (data && data.length) {
        message.channel.send(`Your Name is ${data[0].Name}`);
    }
    else {
        message.channel.send("Your ID can't be found");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had that before but it didnt satisfied my needs :(! What I need is for a variable in this case (z) to be the value that it gets from the function which would be (Boanak) so I could use it later on in if statements

Comment: I just tried it and it works 50%. When the Nameid isnt found it wont show nothing in the console. And I added a, message.channel.send("Your ID cant be found").

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code id that `message.channel.send(`Your Name is ${z}`);` is getting executed before the query returns a result, and hence the output `undefined`.

```
getPlayerid = function(client, message, callback){
    var member = message.member.user;
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('Matches');
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.all(`SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Nameid =`+member.id, 
            function(err, allRows){
               if(err != null){
                 //console.log(err);
                 callback(0);
               }
               callback(allRows);
               db.close();
       });
    });
}


/* moved the statement in the callback function */

z = getPlayerid(client, message, function(data){
    message.channel.send(`Your Name is ${data}`);
});
```

Comment: With this im getting Your name is [object Object]. What I would like to is, z= Boanak , that way I can use the variable in if statements.